# deployable database on CD

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, winforms

I have a Microsoft SQL database that is currently connected to a winforms C# application, it works fine on the single computer, but i would like it to be usable on a CD for any user.

I tried putting it in as a localDb but for some reason the database is duplicated and put into the bin folder, it causes multiple issues in recording data, for instances i save user ID 5 it saves in bin but never makes changes to the real database. Then next i go to create it, the user ID changes to 7 with user 6 not visible in either two databases (yes it is auto incremented by 1)

Any suggestions or best methods on making a database useable and readable via CD if the winform application is also on the CD

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: even if you figure out how to access the DB from original location, it will just be readonly as CD will be readonly. I am not aware there are CDs available which allow random read/write

Comment: MS SQL Server will not mount a database from a read only file like a CD.

Comment: Any other ideas then?

Comment: What is your end goal?

Comment: basically a winforms application which can read and write properly to a database on a portable CD, i have the  SQL script wrote out so i can adapt if needed

Comment: ..."read and write properly to a database on a portable CD"...you're sunk right here.  Random write access to a CD isn't going to happen.  Certainly not with a SQL Server database.  Reconsider your goal.

Comment: ok, so would the likes of a mysql and zwamp sever work?

Comment: Nothing will work if you want to write to a file on a CD, it needs to be copied locally first, CD's aren't read/write in the sense that a drive is.

Comment: oh i understand now, thats fine

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this my self, but according to the documentation SQLite supports read-only databases.

> If the file is read-only (due to permission bits or because it is located on read-only media like a **CD-ROM**) then SQLite opens the database for reading only. The entire SQL database is stored in a single file on the disk. But additional temporary files may be created during the execution of an SQL command in order to store the database rollback journal or temporary and intermediate results of a query.

see https://www.sqlite.org/c_interface.html

.NET SQLite providers are available here:

- https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net
- http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki